# I'm trying to standardize my attribute but I'm getting standard scaler error because Python can not find it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use a standard scaler but Python could not find,
here is the error:

```
z_scaler = Standardscaler() 
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-09f39beade2e> in <module>
----> 1 z_scaler = Standardscaler()

NameError: name 'Standardscaler' is not defined
```

Is there any particular package I need for Standard Scaler?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) , not `Standardscaler`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```